# Sherlock action bar appears twice

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to add the Sherlock action bar to my project and just copied the sample code. The demo app runs fine on pre 4.0 devices but my app shows the action bar twice at the top.
Since I stripped down the relevant code to be the example code and I cannot post my entire project, my simple question is: Did someone see a similar behavior yet? This might guide me to the right direction.
Many thanks!

Manifest simply adds

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

Activity:

```
private ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    mSherlock.getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);
```

Delete the above line of code, as it is not necessary if you are inheriting from an appropriate Sherlock-flavored activity class (e.g., `SherlockActivity`, `SherlockFragmentActivity`). For example, that line does not appear in [the list navigation sample activity](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ListNavigation.java) out on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! I must have merged two examples.